# Не корректное отображение объекта из базы данных

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin

В php не работаю, но понадобился.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то название объектов коверкается, в чем проблема и как исправить???

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$servername = "**********";
$username = "********";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "********";

function connect(){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("*******", "********", "********", "********");
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    return $conn;
}

function init(){
    //вывожу список товаров
    $conn = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT  id, name FROM goods";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $out = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $out[$row["id"]] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($out);
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>




<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
//читать json файл
$json = file_get_contents( '../goods.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);

//письмо
$message = '';
$message .= '<h1>Заказ в магазине</h1>';
$message .='<p>Телефон:  '.$_POST['ephone'].'</p>';
$message .='<p>Почта:  '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
$message .='<p>Клиент:  '.$_POST['ename'].'</p>';


$cart = $_POST['cart'];
$sum = 0;
foreach ($cart as $id=>$count) {
  $message .=$json[$id]['name'].' --- ';
  $message .=$count.' --- ';
  $message .=$count*$json[$id]['cost'];
  $message .='<br>';
  $sum = $sum + $count*$json[$id]['cost'];
}
$message .='Всего: '.$sum;
//print_r($message);

$to = '******************'.',';
$to .=$_POST['email'];
$specttext = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Заказ</title></head><body>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

$m = mail($to, 'Заказ в магазине', $specttext.$message.'</body></html>', $headers);
if ($m) {echo 1;} else {echo 0;}

?>
```

Comment: Кодировка плохая.

Comment: @Manitikyl вроде везде utf-8 стоит

Comment: @korytoff понял) сейчас будет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при работе с mysql указан charset utf8 то попробуй в начале файла добавить

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Можно еще через файл htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

При работе с базой данных, если работаешь через mysql

```
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("db");
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Если через mysqli

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

Если PDO

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

UPD: В твоем случае

```
function connect(){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("*******", "********", "********", "********");
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    return $conn;
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант уже везде прописан) 2-ой - куда можно прописать? 3-вариант тоже не знаю куда. 4 вариант прописан)

Comment: Дополнил. Думаю разберешься. Если нет то кидай кусок кода сюда.

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!