# Кодировка в логах ошибок в chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, mysqli, php7.2

Есть такой код

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
```

он обращается к несуществующему серверу, и в результате выводит в браузер вот это:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): ������ ���������
>   ���������� ��� ����������, �.�. �� ������� �������� �� ��������� ����
>   �� ������ ����� ������, ��� ��� ��������� ��� ������������� ����������
>   ��-�� ��������� ������� ��� ����������� ��������. in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\mysite.local\index.php on line 11

почему так происходит, как исправить кодировку.

Comment: Где вы задали кодировку страницы, кодировку файлов, кодировку соединения? В упор не вижу. Поставьте кодировку `utf8` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: напиши в ответе

Comment: Может это потому что php 7.

Comment: Смотрите в конфигурационном файле `my.ini (windows)`, `my.cnf (другие)`, опцию - 
`default-character-set`, а также смотрите кодировки на стороне `web-server'a` и таблиц.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не корректное отображение объекта из базы данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829496/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: у меня локальный сервак

Comment: покажи что в браузерной консоли в заголовках ответа сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже давал ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829509/247107

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: добавил header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); не помогло

Comment: @StanislavPetrov, файл `i.php` - конвертните в `utf-8 без BOM`.

Comment: он и так без BOM